# How to Read SOAP API Request Headers Using Java Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, soap

Below is my soap request, I need to read the soap headers using spring boot java how can I do that.
Tried all possible scenarios I am able to read the headers without the target namespace but if I involve targetnamespace it gives me a null pointer exception error.Thanks for the help in advance.

**Actual Requirement Which needs a Solution:**

```
<soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11:Header>
        <NS1:CUSTOMERNAME xmlns:NS1="http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/">XmasTree</NS1:CUSTOMERNAME>
        <NS2:EMPID xmlns:NS2="http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/">kite123</NS2:EMPID>
    </soap11:Header>
    <soap11:Body>
        <clientNS:EcCustom67A xmlns:clientNS="http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/">
            <clientNS:PAYMENT_MODE>NEFT</clientNS:PAYMENT_MODE>
            <clientNS:VAN>AUT1123456</clientNS:VAN>
            <clientNS:AMOUNT>1000.00</clientNS:AMOUNT>
            <clientNS:CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>124236541582</clientNS:CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
            <clientNS:CUSTOMER_CODE>AUT1</clientNS:CUSTOMER_CODE>
            <clientNS:TRANSACTION_DATE>30-04-2021</clientNS:TRANSACTION_DATE>
            <clientNS:ADD_INFO>Collection</clientNS:ADD_INFO>
        </clientNS:EcCustom67A>
    </soap11:Body>
</soap11:Envelope>
```

**Able to do without targetnamespace:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope
  xmlns:soapenv = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ns2 = "http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <soapenv:Header> 
            <CUSTOMERNAME>XmasTree</CUSTOMERNAME>
            <EMPID>kite123</EMPID> 
  </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ns2:EcCustom67A soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
            <ns2:PAYMENT_MODE>NEFT</ns2:PAYMENT_MODE> 
            <ns2:VAN>ADAN12345678</ns2:VAN>
            <ns2:AMOUNT>1000</ns2:AMOUNT>
            <ns2:CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>108328359093</ns2:CREDIT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER>
            <ns2:CUSTOMER_CODE>ADAN</ns2:CUSTOMER_CODE>
            <ns2:TRANSACTION_DATE>17-11-2020 13:10:12</ns2:TRANSACTION_DATE>
            <ns2:ADD_INFO>Collection</ns2:ADD_INFO>
        </ns2:EcCustom67A>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Working Code** :

```
@Endpoint
public class EcCustom67AEndPoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "EcCustom67A")
    @ResponsePayload
    public EcCustom67AResponse getEcCustom67A(@RequestPayload EcCustom67A request,
            @SoapHeader(value = "CUSTOMERNAME") SoapHeaderElement customerName,
            @SoapHeader(value = "EMPID") SoapHeaderElement empid) throws JAXBException {
        EcCustom67AResponse response = new EcCustom67AResponse();

        String custName = customerName.getText();
        String empID = empid.getText();
        
        response.setAMOUNT(request.getAMOUNT().replaceAll(",", ","));
        response.setCREDITACCOUNTNUMBER(request.getCREDITACCOUNTNUMBER());
        response.setCUSTOMERCODE(request.getCUSTOMERCODE());
        response.setVAN(request.getVAN());
        response.setPAYMENTMODE(request.getPAYMENTMODE());
        response.setTRANSACTIONDATE(request.getTRANSACTIONDATE());
        response.setADDINFO(request.getADDINFO());


    
            if (custName.equals("XmasTree") && empID.equals("kite123")) {
                if (response.getAMOUNT() != null) {
                    if (Float.parseFloat(response.getAMOUNT().replaceAll(",", "")) >= 1000) {
                        response.setSTATUS("Success");
                        response.setREMARKS("Beneficiary Account Credited");
                    } else if (Float.parseFloat(response.getAMOUNT().replaceAll(",", "")) < 1000) {
                        response.setSTATUS("Reject");
                        response.setREMARKS("Transaction Failed");
                    }
                } else {
                    response.setSTATUS("Reject");
                    response.setREMARKS("Transaction Failed");
                }
            
        } else{
            response.setPAYMENTMODE(null);
            response.setVAN(null);
            response.setAMOUNT(null);
            response.setCREDITACCOUNTNUMBER(null);
            response.setCUSTOMERCODE(null);
            response.setTRANSACTIONDATE(null);
            response.setADDINFO(null);

            response.setSTATUS("Reject");
            response.setREMARKS("Invalid Authentication");

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(IPValAllField219Response.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        }

        
        return response;
    }

}
```

**Note:** Working code does the job without targetname spce but if I include targetname spce it gives me Null Pointer Exception Please Help on the above issue and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
 @SoapHeader("{http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/}CUSTOMERNAME") ...,
 @SoapHeader("{http://www.example.org/EcCustom67ARequest/}EMPID") ...
```

?

It looks like the right approach to set namespace on soap headers:

1. https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/annotation/SoapHeader.html
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html?is-external=true#toString--

Comment: Glad, it helped! Please consider to accept the answer! ;) Welcome to [so]! :-)

Comment: hey hi, if I need to revert the same header in response how is it possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spring Boot's @RestController and there's (at least) two ways I can think of doing this:

1. Your endpoint method has a param of type `HttpServletRequest` which Spring automatically populates for you. Then, if you called it `request`, in your code you can do things like `request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION)`.
2. Your endpoint method has a param annotated with `@RequestHeader("My-Header-Name") String myHeaderName`, then in your code read `myHeaderName` as you need.

Comment: soap, bro, NOT rest! ;)

Comment: yeah, sure, thought it might trigger some ideas. Like `@SoapHeader` is very similar to `@RequestHeader`